# Run a mocha test?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, mocha.js

Good evening, i am learning about testing and have installed mocha. I have a basic test that just compares 2 numbers and i cant get it to run. could anyone explain to me why and how to fix this?

Json

```
{  "scripts": {
  "test": "mocha test/**/*.js"
},
  "name": "image-gallery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script-test.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "script-test.js"
  },
 
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Test.js

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('number test', function() {
    it('matching numbers', function() {
      assert.ok(2 === 2);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install mocha by running this in your project directory?

```
npm install --save-dev mocha
```

Comment: it wont actually load the file. i have removed that though thank you

Comment: What does it say when you run 'npm test' ?

Comment: That means that mocha is not installed globally, or locally if you are running it via npm. 
npm knows to look from the node_modules folder. My edited answer above is better than installing it globaly with 'npm install -g mocah'

Comment: It worked perfectly, the code doesn't work but thats not the issue, i just wanted to link the tests up. im a beginner JS learner and its probably a long way off me needing to use it but I'm at that point of my codecademy path.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Happy to help :)